# How to fire an event handler for a child component in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am new to reactjs. I want to write an event handler handleClick() for a ButtonComponent component in App.js and I want to change the state inside the event-handler.

My App.js:

```
import ButtonComponent from "./ButtonComponent"
class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state={
      isLoggedIn: true
    }
    this.handleClick=this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick() {
    alert("Reached click event handler")
    if(this.state.isLoggedIn===true){
      this.setState(
        {
          isLoggedIn:false
        }
      )
    }
    else{
        //this.state.isLoggedIn=true 
        this.setState(
          {
            isLoggedIn:true
          }
        )
    }
  }

  render() {
    //alert("Reached")
    return (
      <div>
        <ButtonComponent isLoggedIn={this.state.isLoggedIn} onClick={this.handleClick} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

My ButtonComponent.js

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

class ButtonComponent extends Component{
     render(){
        if(this.props.isLoggedIn===true){
            console.log(this.props.isLoggedIn)
            return(
                <button >Logout</button>
            )
        }
        else{
            console.log(this.props.isLoggedIn)
            return(
                <button>Login</button>
            ) 
        }
    }
}


export default ButtonComponent;
```

But the handleClick() event handler isn't firing. There is no error shown, just the event handler isn't executed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `onClick` prop of `ButtonComponent` into the child `<button/>`

```
     render(){
        if(this.props.isLoggedIn===true){
            console.log(this.props.isLoggedIn)
            return(
                <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>Logout</button>
            )
        }
        else{
            console.log(this.props.isLoggedIn)
            return(
                <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>Login</button>
            ) 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are passing `this.handleClick` function as props to `ButtonComponent` you need to use that props to fire `onClick` event from `ButtonComponent`.

Simplified code,

//App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      isLoggedIn: true,
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick() {
    alert('Reached click event handler')
    this.setState({
      isLoggedIn: !this.state.isLoggedIn,
    })
  }

  render() {
    //alert("Reached")
    return (
      <div>
        <ButtonComponent
          isLoggedIn={this.state.isLoggedIn}
          onClick={this.handleClick}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

//ButtonComponent.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class ButtonComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>
        {this.props.isLoggedIn ? 'Logout' : 'Login'}
      </button>
    )
  }
}

export default ButtonComponent
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-42c0t?fontsize=14)